# What's wrong with my dpkg?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04. I recently needed to install a browser other than chromium or Firefox in order to play a flash video. I've now ended up with a much more complicated problem.

Every time I try to do something with dpkg, I get an error code like:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process
```

To try and fix this, I have tried commands such as:

```
 sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

to figure out what the offending process is, but there's nothing there. I've also `sudo rm`ed a bunch of folders like `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock`. No luck, and I have still not been able to install any packages.

I cannot think of a reason behind this, except: I changed my sources.list file recently; and downloading the Chrome (the non-free) browser. I have no idea what the connection would be in either case though. Any ideas what I would be able to do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When starting Ubuntu the autoupdate service will be executed automatically, that's why you received an error, the best practice is to let the auto-update complete this task.

If you need to interrupt this task you can do:

```
sudo pkill apt
sudo pkill dpkg
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 6):

The `dpkg` frontend lock is `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`; make sure no other program is running with a lock on it, using

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

If this doesn’t reveal a running process, delete the file; otherwise, exit the corresponding program (or wait for it to exit). That should allow `dpkg` to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried these but they unfortunately don't produce a result.